# getchar(), isspace() - ошибка с русскими буквами. printf - неверный вывод

Tags: c

В программе считываю символ (русскую букву) функцией getchar() и когда запихиваю ее в функцию isspace() вылетает ошибка Expression:(unsigned)(c+1) <= 256. С английскими буквами все нормально.

Другая проблема в программе, получил результат double. При выводе printf-ом выводится, например, что-то типо этого: 3,500000. А нужно 3.5

Например printf("%f ", (7.0/2));

Была идея сделать вот так : printf("%s.%s, ..........) но с преобразованием в строку тоже возникли проблемы.

Comment: потому что у Вас для русского языка используется utf-8, а isspace не работает для нелатинницы.

Comment: В задании как раз даются эти функции и пример написан на русском.

Comment: К сожалению, 99% методичек в институтах писались 20-30 лет назад. И я более чем уверен, что на турбо си++ под досом с keyrus это все работает. Но вот только сейчас на 1992-1995, а 2016. На улице юникод и стандарт с++.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если у вас не однобайтовая локаль, то используйте [iswspace()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=iswspace&category=3&russian=0).
2. Посмотрите какой-нибудь справочник по `printf()` и семейству. Ваш случай - [модификатор точности](http://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/08/0804.html) (*precision* на картинке ниже):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для отбрасывания нулей нужно в качестве спецификатора формата использовать `g` вместо `f`:

```
printf( "%g %g", 3.5000, 3.5500 ); /* выведет "3.5 3.55" */
```

Comment: Не знаю как объяснить, нужно не регулировать точность, а просто не выводить нули если есть в конце.. и нужно заменить запятую при выводе на точку. как это сделать в C не знаю в C++ есть поток cout

Comment: @j6wj1997, за вид чисел в `printf()` отвечает текущая локаль.  ЕМНИП, `nl_NL`, `French_Canada.1252` или какие-то ещё. А для отбрасывания нулей нужно в качестве спецификатора формата указывать не `f`, а `g` (при этом все возможности модификатора точности - те же) .

Comment: Проблема найдена. без русской локали работает, но мне нужна русская локаль.

Comment: @j6wj1997 `printf()` для форматирования использует настройки локали, это прошито и изменить невозможно. Поэтому варианта два: 1) не использовать `printf()` вообще, придумать что-то своё. 2) написать wrapper, который устанавливал бы нужную локаль, вызывал бы `printf()` и возвращал старую.

Comment: Просто для нормальной работы с числами установите "С" -- локаль `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` (можно в нужном месте, потом можно переустановить если, например, потребуется вводить числа в "русском" формате (запятая вместо точки (какой ...ак это придумал?))

Comment: По поводу wide characters (iswspace и т.п.) учтите, что есть одна неприятность (мягко говоря). При попытке ввода неправильной кодовой последовательности поток ввода необратимо (ну, почти) портится. Поэтому для серьезных ("железобетонных") программ все равно придется делать все преобразования самому.

Comment: Не уходите ребят. Все то я исправил спасибо. Но щас не знаю почему не работает вот этоо например: setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); char str[1000]; cin >> str; cout << str; не работает русский язык, извините, мой пукан уже разрывается, я не понимаю почему)

Comment: Может я в самой консоли что-то не то вижу

Comment: @j6wj1997, тут явно Windows, а что там с локалями (и вообще, корректна ли локаль "rus", какую кодировку она подразумевает, и тд) я не знаю. Под Linux, например, с родной локалью "ru_RU.UTF-8" это прекрасно работает: `cin >> str; cout << str; `. Раскапывать и запускать винды под виртуалкой на ночь глядя ну очень обломно :)

Answer (score 0):

> При выводе printf-ом выводится, например, что-то типо этого: 3,500000.
>   А нужно 3.5

Ну напишите `printf("%.1f\n", (7.0/2));`

Что до русского... Ну, VC++2015 такого не дает. Надо конкретнее смотреть - для каких символов, как вы их вводите, что за локаль и компилятор...